# Windows 10 in Azure VM - NET 3.5 installation error 0x8000FFFF

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, .net-framework, azure

I just created a new Compute in Azure - choosing `Windows 10 Enterprise (x64)` image. For deployment I used Resource Manager mode, DS1 size, disk type Standard and left default for the rest of options.

I needed .NET Framework 3.5 (as prerequisite for some 3rd party SW) so I went to Windows features and clicked on .NET 3.5

It ended up with error:

```
Catastrophic failure
Error code: 0x8000FFFF
```

Googling the issue I found two types of solution: 1) using installation source (DVD), which I don't have for Azure image for their marketplace, 2) Uninstall specific security updates before adding this feature but those are not on this fresh Win 10.

What to try more?

Comment: You can mount an .iSO then install the feature from the .ISO.  of course `0x8000FFFF` indicates a larger problem then you might realize.

Comment: @Ramhound plaese elaborate a bit more - how can I access/mount ISO for the image from Azure marketplace? Are the images available for all items in Azure marketplace?

Comment: You can transfer the files contained within the .iso or mount the .iso through a command.  Don't know if you have remote desktop capabilities of the VM or not, not 100% familiar, with the management options for Azure.

Comment: I can remote desktop to the VM and technically I could mount some ISO. But I don't have one. There's a marketplace of images in Azure. I'm not even sure if even for the operating systems they are exactly the same as the retail image. The point why I'm using cloud is that I don't need to have local installers - I just want to launch VM from image I choose in the marketplace (having license fees covered in the price of the service).

Comment: You need an Enterprise .ISO, Professional or Home wouldn't be applicable in a case like this, you might be better of just scrapping the image and rebuilding the virtual machine.  You *should* be able to use the Enterprise Trial .ISO for the purposes of using it as a source for the .NET Framework.  If that does not work then, honestly, the next idea I have is contact Azure support and request assistance.  I strongly suspect the image your using simply does not have the feature available to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered in https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f7so7/catastrophic_failure_0x8000ffff_when_trying_to/

The problem is with the Profile List of Windows. If you delete the user wich install Windows, then you cannot install .Net 3.5 unless you update te registry.

Comment: You should quote any relevant information from your link and provide specific instructions on how to "update the registry"

Comment: As you can see in the question, it is fresh install without any modification. I didn't delete any user.